# configure virtual hosts in hippo cms

Tags: java, configuration, localhost, virtualhost, hippocms

I am new in Hippo cms, need your help!
I create my hippo project and started using Cargo, URL is: http://localhost:8080/site/. All works good. 
But me need access to this site from another IP, I am using virtual hosts and this is not works. Please help solve my issue!!!!

Comment: How you are accessing ??

Comment: I am using this documentation
http://www.onehippo.org/library/enterprise/installation-and-configuration/configure-virtual-hosts-in-an-environment.html

Comment: my configuration:gyazo.com/d4131a0f918ecfe669cf15c02ab2055c; accessing testlocal:8080/cms

Answer (score 0):

Virtual hosts should work for what you're trying to do.
Could you explain

1. what's the full URL on which you want to access the /site portion?
2. What's the full URL on which you want to access the /cms portion?

I took a look at your configuration and reproduced it on my machine. I added testlocal to my hosts file and pointed it to 127.0.0.1 and it works.

Do remember that the CMS is always accessible via /cms, it doesn't need to be mapped via virtual host. This means that 127.0.0.1:8080/cms should work just as well on a local machine (with the exception of the channel manager).

This means you could go to the IP of the machine hosting your site http://123.123.123.1:8080/cms and you should be able to login.

Could you try that and let me know what the results are?

Regards,
Dodo